# Reading a .config file

Tags: javascript, node.js

Currently I have a file called router.js set up as follows:

```
var Server = require('mongodb').Server;
var MongoDB = require('mongodb').Db;
var dbPort = 31979;
var dbHost = '40.117.155.19';
var dbName = 'node-login';
```

I would like to to be set up like this:

```
var Server = require('mongodb').Server;
var MongoDB = require('mongodb').Db;
var dbPort      = readConfig(dbPort);
var dbHost      = readConfig(dbHost);
var dbName      = readConfig(dbName);
```

How would I go about accomplishing this. I would like to have a file such as test.config, and be able to read dbPort, dbHost, and dbName from that .config file in router.js.

Comment: You could manually read it with the fs module and parse it. However JavaScript and JSON go hand in hand. Using a .config would be like using classical inheritance in Js, possible but not the best way to do it.

Answer (score 47):

You could store your config as a JSON file and read it directly:

**config.json**

```
{
    "dbPort": 31979,
    "dbHost": "40.117.155.19",
    "dbName": "node-login"
}
```

**router.js**

```
var Server = require('mongodb').Server;
var MongoDB = require('mongodb').Db;
var CONFIG = require('./config.json');

var dbPort = CONFIG.dbPort;
var dbHost = CONFIG.dbHost;
var dbName = CONFIG.dbName;
```

Comment: Does this need requirejs?

Comment: IMHO, json is [too simplistic](https://revelry.co/json-configuration-file-format/) for everyday configuration needs. And, yes @JoshuaKissoon, `requires.js` must be installed.

Answer (score 10):

Here's one way to do it

```
//File config.js
module.exports = {
  dbPort : 8080,
  dbHost : etc,
  dbName : nom,
}

//File server.js
var Server  = require('mongodb').Server;
var MongoDB = require('mongodb').Db;
var config  = require('configFile');

var dbPort      = config.dbPort;
var dbHost      = config.dbHost;
var dbName      = config.dbName;
```

Comment: You could technically name the file '.config' and still read it if it's properly formatted JSON. Unless you mean some specific Android config file type.

Comment: great thank you, that answers my question. And no, I don't mean some specific Android config file type, appreciate the help. I'd give you a +1, but unfortunately I think this is the first question I've bothered to ask on stackoverflow.

Comment: module.exports = {
  dbPort : 8080,
  dbHost : 'etc',
  dbName : 'nom',
}

Please add strings notations.